# pd4ml set default print to pdf option as portrait in java

Tags: java, pdf

I am using `pd4ml` for converting HTML to PDF. But while printing the PDF it is showing the page in landscape view. I want to make portrait as default view. In my Java file I have set the following parameters. In addition to this, I want to set dynamic header to my PDF page. I am completely new to this.

```
protected Dimension format = PD4Constants.A4;
protected boolean landscapeValue = false;
protected int topValue = 6;
protected int leftValue = 6;
protected int rightValue = 6;
protected int bottomValue = 6;
protected int userSpaceWidth = 800;
```